# How to get outputs from 'check' task in Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle, report, pmd

I am using java **plugin** and I add *checkstyle*, *pmd* and *findbugs* checks. So when they are done I want to get their output file reports. I tried

```
project.tasks.getByName("check").getOutputs().each {
    println "------------>"+ it
}
```

But nothing happens.

How can I get generated reports?

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve.  The contents of the report files or the list of report files?

Comment: I need the path for this files so after that to upload them somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle, pmd and findbugs simply add dependencies to the java plugin check task so that the reporting tasks are called.  I don't think you can get any information about reports from java's check task.

For the checkstyle plugin there is the checkstyleMain task that is added as a dependency to java's check task.  If the checkstyleMain task fails it prints out a failure message that tells you where the report is:

```
 Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///Users/foo/bar/sandbox/gradle/build/reports/checkstyle/main.xml
```

You could do this to print the content of the report.

```
project.gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    if (buildResult.getFailure() != null) {
        println "Reports: " + checkstyleMain.reports.getXml().getDestination().text
    }
}
```

I'm not certain this is what you are after and have added a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: The reports are saved in build/reports/pmd or findbugs ... but I am asking if there is more elegant way to do this. Checkstyle's xmls can be found in build/reports/checkstyle, but when i rerun my tests without clean tests are UPTODATE if incremental build is on, that means that there are define inputs and outputs, or I am not right?

Comment: You can get the report locations with code such as `checkstyleMain.reports.xml.destination`. For details, check the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).